# build Solr suggester with dynamic field

Tags: solr, lucene

My understanding is that "suggest" has to be a handler defined in SolrConfig.xml. And the handler needs to have one of more defined (search) component(s).  The search component syntax needs dictionary (or file) or a indexed field to search on as per [Solr Ref Guide 6.6](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/suggester.html).   In my case, i have a dynamic fields and need to build a suggester for two fields but unfortunately could not find any  reference or documentation that explain how to use this feature with dynamic fields.

Answer (score 1):

the 'dynamic' nature of the field just means that use can use a pattern to give the field type for a bunch of different possible field names. Once the dynamic field gets the field type, it can be used like a normal field. At Lucene level a dynamic field and a normal field will not have any difference. So you can use your dynamic field just fine to build the suggester.